# What is the way to ignore/skip some issues from python bandit security issues report?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, bandit-python

I've got a bunch of `django_mark_safe` errors

```
>> Issue: [B703:django_mark_safe] Potential XSS on mark_safe function.
   Severity: Medium   Confidence: High
   Location: ...
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b703_django_mark_safe.html
54 return mark_safe(f'<a href="{url}" target="_blank">{title}</a>')

>> Issue: [B308:blacklist] Use of mark_safe() may expose cross-site scripting vulnerabilities and should be reviewed.
   Severity: Medium   Confidence: High
   Location: ...
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklists/blacklist_calls.html#b308-mark-safe
54 return mark_safe(f'<a href="{url}" target="_blank">{title}</a>')
```

And I'm curious if there is a way to skip or ignore such lines? I understand that using `mark_safe` could  be dangerous, but what if I want to take the risk? For example this method is the only way to display custom link in Django admin, so I don't know any other option how to do it without `mark_safe`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I've got an answer [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/issues/395#issuecomment-426078552):

> Two ways:
>
> 1. You can skip the B703 and B308 using the --skip argument to the
>    command line.
> 2. Or you can affix a comment `# nosec` on the line to skip.
>
> https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#exclusions

Answer (score 17):

### Heads up for annotating multilines with `# nosec`:

**given:**

```
li_without_nosec = [
    "select * from %s where 1 = 1 "
    % "foo"
]

li_nosec_at_start_works = [  # nosec - ✅ and you can put a comment
    "select * from %s where 1 = 1 "
    % "foo"
]  

# nosec - there's an enhancement request to marker above line
li_nosec_on_top_doesntwork = [  
    "select * from %s where 1 = 1 "
    % "foo"
]  

li_nosec_at_end_doesntwork = [
    "select * from %s where 1 = 1 "
    % "foo"
]  # nosec
```

**output:**

```
>> Issue: [B608:hardcoded_sql_expressions] Possible SQL injection vector through string-based query construction.
   Severity: Medium   Confidence: Low
   Location: test.py:3
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b608_hardcoded_sql_expressions.html
2   li_without_nosec = [
3       "select * from %s where 1 = 1 "
4       % "foo"
5   ]

--------------------------------------------------
>> Issue: [B608:hardcoded_sql_expressions] Possible SQL injection vector through string-based query construction.
   Severity: Medium   Confidence: Low
   Location: test.py:15
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b608_hardcoded_sql_expressions.html
14  li_nosec_on_top_doesntwork = [
15      "select * from %s where 1 = 1 "
16      % "foo"
17  ]

--------------------------------------------------
>> Issue: [B608:hardcoded_sql_expressions] Possible SQL injection vector through string-based query construction.
   Severity: Medium   Confidence: Low
   Location: test.py:21
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b608_hardcoded_sql_expressions.html
20  li_nosec_at_end_doesntwork = [
21      "select * from %s where 1 = 1 "
22      % "foo"
23  ]  # nosec
```

### Black

Here's hoping that [black](https://github.com/psf/black) won't get involved and restructure the lines, moving the `# nosec` around.

so much for hope... **black** does move things around, just like it does with pylint directives, whenever the line length becomes too long.  At which point `# nosec` ends up at the end.

You can either proactively break up the line and position `# nosec` at the first one.  Or you can just wait out black and adjust if needed.

Comment: Suppose I have a multi-line like this: assert(10<20,"a very long multiline message with \ for better readability....") then where do I place the #nosec?

Comment: @variable not sure.  You could enter a new question outright, with your actual sample code, tag it bandit and link to this question (ping/DM me in a comment if you do that) and we can look for an answer.  Unfortunately, until bandit allows top-of-code annotation comments, like pylint, the answer may be tightly coupled to your particular code's format so it is hard to reason about without seeing your code.  Also, FWIW, if you use mypy, I think mypy `# type: ignore` are also operating with the same constraints as bandit so you could check what people are up to there.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to apply the rule in a local piece of your code you can do something like the following:

```py
# this is my very basic python script

def foo():
   do_something_unsecure()  # nosec B703, B308
```

In that way you will skip those validations just in that line. In real work it can be probably the most appropriated way to skip some rules.

Answer (score 9):

Just to complete the topic - in my case I had to rid of `B322: input` rule, and didn't wanted to write `# nosec` each time I found this problem in the code, or to always execute Bandit with a `--skip` flag.

So if you want to omit a certain rule for whole solution, you can create a `.bandit` file in the root of your project. Then you can write which rules should be skipped every time, for example:

```
[bandit]
skips: B322
```

And then Bandit will skip this check by default without need to give additional comments in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can config Bandit with `.bandit` INI file (only if it is invoked with `-r` option):

```ini
[bandit]
tests = B101,B102,B301
```

Or with `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[tool.bandit]
tests = ["B201", "B301"]
skips = ["B101", "B601"]
```

Or with yaml file:

```yaml
skips: ['B101', 'B601']
assert_used:
  skips: ["*/test_*.py", "*/test_*.py"]
```

See https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

Comment: I was confused how you can use `assert_used` as a key in the config file -- it's not a listed in the main config.html -- This will configure each plugin based on the plugin name, see i.e. https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.5/plugins/b101_assert_used.html